# LED, or LED backlit LCD monitor

Tags: drivers

I have installed windows 8, and I need to get updated drivers for my HP2311x.

Oddly, there are two very different product support pages at hp.com for this model number:

[HP 2311x 23 inch Diagonal LED Monitor Drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&lc=en&product=5076897)

and

[Drivers, Software & Firmware for HP 2311x 23-inch LED Backlit LCD Monitor](https://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5096577)

...though the pictures of a monitor on each page look identical (and just like my monitor, of course.)

Could these be actually the same product?? If not, how can I tell whether I have an LED, or an LED backlit LCD monitor. I bought this quite a long time ago; the packaging and receipt are gone.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_display vs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED-backlit_LCD_display

Comment: Unless the display specifically mentions AMOLED or PMOLED then chances are it is simply an LED backlit LCD display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "LED" monitors and televisions are LCD devices with a LED backlight instead of a CCFL backlight. There is no difference between the two.